# Read a csv file using scala and generate analytics

Tags: scala

I have started learning scala and I have tryed to solve a scenario as below. I have an input file with multiple transactions separated by ','. Below are my sample values:

```
transactionId, accountId, transactionDay, category, transactionAmount

A11,A45,1,SA,340
A12,A2,1,FD,567
```

and **I have to calculate the total transaction value for all transactions for each day along with other statistics**. Below is my initial snippet

```
import scala.io.Source 
val fileName = "<path of input file>" 
Transaction( 
  transactionId: String, accountId: String, 
  transactionDay: Int, category: String, 
  transactionAmount: Double)   
Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().drop(1) 
val transactions: List[Transaction] = transactionslines.map { line => 
  val split = line.split(',') Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3), split(4).toDouble) }.toList
```

Comment: Where is question?

Comment: `group` + `map` + `reduce`.

Comment: @Scalway,for your reference I have highlighted my query in bold.Thanks Luis,but if you could elaborate a bit then it would help me understanding it better.

Comment: @Durga give it a look to the [**Scaladoc** for `List`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) it has a lot of useful methods. Particularly for this problem you only need three `groupBy`, `map` & `reduce`. Or if you can use **Scala** `2.13` then you can just use `gruopMapReduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as below:

```
val sd=transactions.groupBy(_.transactionDay).mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum)
```

Further ,you can do complex analytics by converting it into a dataframe.

```
val scalatoDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(transactions).toDF("transactionId","accountId","transactionDay","category","transactionAmount")

scalatoDF.show()
```

Hope this helps!